# javascript, get indices of given value in array

Tags: javascript

This JavaScript code tries to get the indices of a given value 5 in a new array. Any idea how to do it in an elegant way. I cold use for loop but I was hoping to use map or reduce. thx.

```js
console.log( [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 5].map((y, i) => {
  if (y === 5) return i
}))
// gives --> [undefined, undefined, undefined, 3, undefined, 5]
// expected [3,5]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately `map` and `reduce` are not lazily-evaluated in JavaScript (i.e. they're not generators/iterators), but if you don't mind the double array allocation, you can do this:

```
var indices = [ 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 5 ]
    .map( ( e, i ) => e == 5 ? i : -1 )
    .filter( e => e > -1 );

// indicies == [3,5]
```

Another approach, that's cheaper:

```
var indices = [];
[ 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 5 ].forEach( (e, i) => e == 5 ? indices.push( i ) : null );
```

This takes advantage of the fact you can use a `void` expression inside the `?:` ternary operator.

Comment: is forEach in this case cheaper than the for loop I posted?

Comment: @FredJ. There is no `for` loop in your question. You have to define "cheap" for an answer. The simplest solution would be a `for` loop. I would go with `.reduce()` to only iterate the array once.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce`. The third argument of the callback is the index.

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 5].reduce((indexes, n, index) => {
  if (n === 5) indexes.push(index)
  return indexes
}, [])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either use `map()` or `reduce()`.

`reduce()` will be able to do it in a single loop:

```
[1,2,3,4,5].reduce((result, num, index) => result.concat(num === 5 ? index : []), []);
```

Using `concat()` instead of `push()` is a tiny bit slower, but cleaner, and in reasonably small sets, the difference will be negligible.

`map()` will need `filter()` to remove extras:

```
[1,2,3,4,5].map((num, index) => num === 5 && index)
    .filter(e => e !== false);
```

`.filter(Boolean)` is a clean, short-hand way of casting whatever value to a Boolean, which filter will then use to determine what it needs to do. `num === 5 && index` will be either `false` or the index. Another clean way to go through.

Comment: Using the second method, if we have `[5, 1, 5]`, it returns `[2]`. Because `Boolean(0)` is `false`

Comment: Oops, indeed. Good catch. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **reduce** operator on your array as:

```
 [1,2,3,5,6,5].reduce(function(a, e, i) {
        if (e === 5)
            a.push(i);
        return a;
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could run a map to test the value and write either a null (no match) or the position (match) then a filter to remove the nulls.

The map would look like this:

```
map( (value, index) => {
  return value === 5 ? index : null;
})
```

Then you'd filter it like this:

```
filter( (value) => {
  return value != null;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log( [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 5].map((y, i) => {
  if (y === 5) return i
}).filter((x) => {return /\d/.test(x);}));
```